# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement imaplib (from versions: none)

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to read user emails via python email & imaplib package and print the contents in the console. But I'm getting error when I try to install imaplib library in pycharm. I also tried upgrading the pip, still unable to install the package. What could be the cause and how do I solve it?

```
 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement imaplib (from versions: none)
 ERROR: No matching distribution found for imaplib
```

Comment: The answer is a Google search away: https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html#module-imaplib, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol

Comment: Did you not google this? https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html

Answer (score 2):

no need to install `imaplib` library with pip, it is a python core library.
Just import it:

`import imaplib`

Answer (score 0):

The Internet Message Access Protocol (IMAP) is a mail protocol used for accessing email on a remote web server from a local client.Likely using IMAP library you can create folders, move/delete/send messages in python.You can check out my code using IMAP [here](https://github.com/gouthamssc/mail-from-python) and have a better understanding.